# How can I recover files from a "removed" storage space drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, storage-spaces

Quick Statement: I need to recover data from a 4TB Storage Space drive that was "removed" from the array but hasn't been touched since.

Details: I'm in real trouble here. I have a large Windows 8.1 Pro storage array and I'd reached the 15.8TB limit because of the 4K cluster size. I had about 36TB worth of disk so 6TB was going unused. My plan was to start a new array, formatting disks with a larger cluster size, and moving the data over.

I bought a new enclosure and a pair of 8TB disks. Formatted them to 16K clustersizes and copied over 7TB of data with no problem.

Then I wanted to migrate the disks. My process would be to remove one physically (since you can't just tell Storage Spaces on Windows 8.1 to rebalance), "Remove" it in the GUI and wait for the "Repair" to finish before repeating the process so I'd have two new drives for the new array.

During the "Repair", I lost a 1TB drive that was 50% full. Now the array refuses to come up with a disk letter - Storage Spaces offers me the option of removing it but I don't want to as there is some irreplaceable data that may be on the disk as I will now have lost TWO drives.

The 4TB disk that I removed hasn't been touched. I can plug it in and the system sees "Disk #14" as a 4TB drive - but I can't "re-add" it to the array (the thought being that I can 'remove' the 1TB drive, do the repair with the 4TB drive in place and continue from there)

Is there any way I can somehow get the data off the 4TB drive so that I at least have the files that might be missing if I "remove" the faulty 1TB drive? (Those would be the files who's two copies were on those two drives)

I was planning on doing the Windows 10 Pro upgrade after I finished this and then Mirroring the "Pictures" part of the array - the irreplaceable stuff - to OneDrive.

I desperately need help!